# call function inside data() property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-cli

I'm trying to fetching some data for my search tree and i'm not able to get the data directly from axios or to call a function because it can't find this.

```
export default {
 name: 'SideNavMenu',
 data () {
  return {
      searchValue: '',
      treeData: this.getData(),
      treeOptions: {

        fetchData(node) {
          this.onNodeSelected(node)

        }
      },
  }
},
```

In the data() I have treeOptions where I want to call a function called onNodeSelected. The error message is:

"TypeError: this.onNodeSelected is not a function"

can anybody help?

Comment: You should make a `method: fetchWithAxios() { ... }` have it place the information in `this.treeData`, the method should be called in `beforeCreate:`.

Comment: I want to add children to the tree dynamically so if I do it in beforeCreate I don't think I would be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When using `this`, you try to call on a member for the *current* object.

In JavaScript, using the `{}` is actually creating a new object of its own and therefore, either the object needs to implement `onNodeSelected` or you need to call a different function that will allow you to call it on an object that implements the function.

```
export default {
    name: 'SideNavMenu',
    data () {
        return {
            searchValue: '',
            treeData: this.getData(), // <--- This
            treeOptions: {

            fetchData(node) {
                this.onNodeSelected(node) // <--- and this
            }
        },
    }
},


//are calling functions in this object :
{
    searchValue: '',
    treeData: this.getData(),
    treeOptions: {
    fetchData(node) {
        this.onNodeSelected(node)
    }
},
//instead of the object you probably are thinking
```

I would avoid creating object blocks within object blocks like those as the code quickly becomes unreadable and rather create functions within a single object when needed.

I am guessing you would have the same error message if you tried to get a value from `treeData` as well

Comment: In VueJS, `this.` points to the current object, in this case, `this` = `export.default.` where `getData()` can be a function inside the `method:` section...

Comment: I'm getting the right data from the call: treeData: this.getData() but not able to get it from  fetchData function why is that?

Comment: True, my answer applies to JavaScript and might differ from the actual solution for VueJS. However, maybe you can find some clues in it to find your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function, or returning anything from it. Perhaps you're trying to do this?

```
export default {
 name: 'SideNavMenu',
 data () {
  return {
      searchValue: '',
      treeData: this.getData(),
      treeOptions: fetchData(node) {
          return this.onNodeSelected(node)
      },
  }
},
```

Regardless, it is not considered good practice to put functions inside data properties.
Try declaring your variables with empty values first, then setting them when you get the data inside beforeCreate, created, or mounted hooks, like so:

```
export default {
  name: 'SideNavMenu',
  data () {
    return {
      searchValue: '',
      treeData: [],
      treeOptions: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData(){
      // get data here
    },
    fetchData(node){
       this.onNodeSelected(node).then(options => this.treeOptions = options)
    }
  },
  mounted(){
     this.getData().then(data => this.treeData = data)
  }
},
```

Or if you're using async await:

```
export default {
  name: 'SideNavMenu',
  data () {
    return {
      searchValue: '',
      treeData: [],
      treeOptions: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData(){
      // get data here
    },
    async fetchData(node){
       this.treeOptions = await this.onNodeSelected(node) 
    }
  },
  async mounted(){
     this.treeData = await this.getData()
  }
},
```